# Excel Stocks feature for futures

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I am learning how to use Excel's Data type feature for stocks.
Currently, for regular stocks, I find it simple to use. I was wondering though how can I access futures data, such as Nasdaq JUN21 futures?

Comment: You need a data source that Excel can access.

Comment: If there is a website that shows futures data, then you could use Excel Power Query to create a connection.